# login validate servlet from mysql database

Tags: html, servlets, jdbc

I tried to create a simple login form which takes username&password,checks with the mysql database table.Pardon me I'm a beginner to this java stuff...If its matches its re-directed to home page.But i can't execute it.can somebody help me out with this.Thanks for the quick reply.The tomcat error i'm getting is The requested resource (/UserDemo/firstserv) is not available.And i  know there are more errors in it.Thats y i'm posting it here....help me out....

SerExam.java

```
 package myPack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class SerExam extends HttpServlet
{
      Connection con;
      PreparedStatement ps;
      ResultSet rs;
      public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException
      {
            try
               {
                        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","tiger");
               }
                  catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                     {
                        System.out.println(e);
                     }
                  catch (SQLException e)
                     {
                        System.out.println(e);
                     }
      }
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
      {
            doPost(request, response);
            {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
                String username=request.getParameter("username");
                String password=request.getParameter("password");
                pw.println("<html><body>");
                try
                {
                      ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from loginvalidation where username=? and password=?");
                      ps.setString(1, username);
                      ps.setString(2, password);
                      rs=ps.executeQuery();
                      if(rs.next())
                      {
                            pw.println("<h3>welcome " +" " + username +"</h3>");
                            RequestDispatcher rd1=request.getRequestDispatcher("./home.html");
                            rd1.include(request,response);
                            //or
                            //response.sendRedirect("./home.html");
                            pw.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"Login.html\">");
                            pw.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"logout\" " + "value=\"Logout\">");
                            pw.println("</form>");

                      }
                      else
                      {
                            pw.println("<center><h3>invalid username/password Enter Correct username/password</h3></center>");
                            RequestDispatcher rd2=request.getRequestDispatcher("./Login.html");
                            rd2.include(request,response);
                            //or
                            //response.sendRedirect("./Login.html");
                      }
                }
                catch (SQLException e)



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    }
    }
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="./firstserv" method="post">
username &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br>
<br>
password &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="password" name="password"></input><br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="login"></input>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="./reg.html">new user</a>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

reg.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
registration page under construction...............

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>UserDemo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>SerExam</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SerExam</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        myPack.SerExam</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SerExam</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your servlet mapping tag as

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerExam</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then you can use `MyServlet` as the action parameter of your form so that the request with the form parameters is sent to you servlet `SerExam` as per above servlet mapping.

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post">
```

and as you are using `POST` method inside form then your servlets `doPost` method will be called and I can see from your code that you have not written any code inside your `doPost` method.

Remove that `doPost(request,response);` (that is the first line inside your `doGet` method.

So change your servlet code as :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
       //your existing code inside doGet with that doPost call removed   
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

     doGet(request,response);
}
```

Still there are many things you will require to be done before your code works well.

So I would request you to look at our [Servlet wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) so that you can get the basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet is mapped to `/home.html`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerExam</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

while you are accessing `firstserv`:

```
<form action="./firstserv" method="post">
```

---

Side note:

**Never, ever store passwords in plain text** in your database:

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from loginvalidation where username=? and password=?");
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, password);
```